# Why is my BufferedImages not overlapping correctly?

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am trying to write a little beginner program that will just display a couple of BufferedImages that you can move around and put on top of each other. I am having trouble however to get the images on the screen to overlap correctly.

I want the image that is selected with the mouse cursor to be the one moved, even when several images exist within the location of the mouse cursor.

This is what I am having trouble doing; it chooses the upper image only when only 1 image is beneath, so it works when only two images are stacked. However, If I have three images stacked or more which all share a location, and I try to move the image on top, it chooses the one at the bottom of the stack as the selected one to move or just (it seems) randomly any image but the upper one to move. Why is this? I want the upper one to keep being selected when clicked even when many are stacked.

This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;


class Image {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private BufferedImage front, back;
    private StringBuffer filepath;
    private boolean isTurned;

    public Image(int x, int y, String filepath) throws IOException {
        this.filepath = new StringBuffer(filepath);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.front = ImageIO.read(new File(String.valueOf(filepath)));
        this.back = ImageIO.read(new File(String.valueOf("images/back.gif")));
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){

        g.drawImage(front, x, y, null);

    }

    public void undraw (Graphics g, Color c ){
        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillRect(x,y, front.getWidth(), front.getHeight());

    }

    public boolean containsXY (int x, int y){

        if ( (this.x <= x ) && (x <= (this.x+this.front.getWidth())) && (this.y <= y ) && (y <= (this.y+this.front.getHeight()))  ){

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void move (Graphics g, int x, int y) {

        undraw(g, Color.WHITE);
        this.x = x-(this.front.getWidth()/2);
        this.y = y-(this.front.getHeight()/2);
        draw(g);
    }

    public String getFilePath(){
        return String.valueOf(filepath);
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }

    public void turn(Graphics g) throws IOException {

        if (isTurned) {

            undraw(g, Color.WHITE);
            front = ImageIO.read(new File(String.valueOf(filepath)));
            draw(g);
            isTurned = false;
        }

        else {

            undraw(g, Color.WHITE);
            front = back;
            draw(g);
            isTurned = true;
        }
    }

}



class PaintSurface extends JLabel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    private int x, y;
    private JButton browse;
    private Collection<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();
    private final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    private Image selected;
    private boolean drawOnce;
    private Image[] initialImages = new Image[8];

    public PaintSurface(JButton b){
        browse = b;
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        browse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                int x = fc.showOpenDialog(browse);

                if (x == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                    try {
                        buttonPressed(fc);

                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                else if (x ==JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION){
                    System.out.println("No file selected.");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (!drawOnce) {
            try {
                drawStartUpImages();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        for (Image i: images){
            i.draw(g);

        }

        drawOnce = true;

    }

    public void drawStartUpImages() throws IOException {

        initialImages[0] = new Image(0, 100, "images/blab.gif");
        initialImages[1] = new Image(100, 100, "images/fred.gif");
        initialImages[2] = new Image(200, 100, "images/gira.gif");
        initialImages[3] = new Image(300, 100, "images/katt.gif");
        initialImages[4] = new Image(0, 300, "images/pear.gif");
        initialImages[5] = new Image(100, 300, "images/peli.gif");
        initialImages[6] = new Image(200, 300, "images/stef.gif");
        initialImages[7] = new Image(300, 300, "images/stru.gif");

        for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
            addImage(initialImages[i]);
            repaint();
        }



    }

    public void addImage(Image i){
        images.add(i);

        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        i.draw(g);


    }

    public void buttonPressed(JFileChooser fc) throws IOException {


        File selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
        String filepath = String.valueOf(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Image i = new Image(x, y, filepath );
        selected = i;
        addImage(i);


        repaint();

    }

    public Image findImage(int x, int y){

        for (Image i: images){
            if (i.containsXY(x, y)){
                return i;

            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    public void moveImage (Image i, int x, int y) { //

        i.move(getGraphics(), x, y);
    }

    public boolean removeImage(Image i){

        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        i.undraw(g, Color.WHITE);

        return images.remove(i);

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        //selected = findImage(e.getX(), e.getY());

        if (selected != null && findImage(x,y) == selected) {

            Graphics g = getGraphics();
            try {
                selected.turn(g);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        if (findImage(e.getX(), e.getY()) != null){
            selected = findImage(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }

        if ( (findImage(e.getX(), e.getY()) != null && findImage(e.getX(), e.getY()) == selected) ){

            removeImage(selected);
            addImage(selected);

        }

        if ((findImage(e.getX(), e.getY()) != null && findImage(e.getX(), e.getY()) != selected)) {


            try {
                selected = new Image(findImage(e.getX(), e.getY()).getX(), findImage(e.getX(), e.getY()).getY(), findImage(e.getX(), e.getY()).getFilePath());
                removeImage(findImage(e.getX(), e.getY()));
                addImage(selected);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();

        if (selected != null) {
            moveImage(selected,x,y);
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
class GUI extends JFrame {

    public GUI(){
        super("ImageApp");

        JLabel instruction = new JLabel("Clicking on the screen will set the location for the next added image.");
        JButton browse = new JButton("Add image");
        JButton line = new JButton("Line up");
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JLabel panel2 = new PaintSurface(browse);
        panel1.setLayout(null);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        instruction.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        getContentPane().add("North", instruction);
        getContentPane().add("South", browse);

        add(panel2);
        setBounds(300,0,800,800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);

    }





}


public class PhotoApp extends GUI {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        GUI PhotoApplication = new GUI();
    }
}
```

Forgive me if this code is bad, I am only trying to get the overlap to work correctly. I think the problem arises in the PaintSurface class, inside the Mouselistener functions MousePressed and MouseDragged. I have tried alot but I can't seem to get it to keep choosing the upper image when several other images are under it and I click on the top one. It selects one underneath and redraws it as the top one. Like I said, it works when only two images are stacked on top of each other, only then is it not choosing the one underneath when I click. Does anyone know how I get the overlapping to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're `findImage()`method always returns the first match in your `ArrayList`.

In your `mousePressed()` method you first set `selected` to `findImage()` and afterwards you're checking if `selected == findImage()` so that will always be true.
Then you're removing the Image from the `ArrayList` and add it again at the end,
so if there are multiple Images at this position the next if clause will always
be true, because you're selected Image is now at the end and `findImage()` will return another Image at this position.

First of all you could do:

`if (findImage(e.getX(), e.getY()) == null) { 
    return;
}`

At the beginning of `mousePressed` because it`s in every if clause.

After that you're able to do something like this:

`if (findImage(e.getX(), e.getY()) == selected) ){
       [...]
     } else {
       [...]
     }`

so now only one of your original if clauses will be executed at time.

Hope with this little help you're able to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the help but it still doesn't work . I changed the mousepressed method to what you said and now it changes the selected picture even when only 2 images are stacked to the one at the bottom?

Comment: I did this: `if (findImage(e.getX(), e.getY()) == null) {
            return;
        }

  if ( (findImage(e.getX(), e.getY()) == selected) ){
         removeImage(selected);
         addImage(selected);

        }
        else {
            try {
                selected = new Image(findImage(e.getX(), e.getY()).getX(), findImage(e.getX(), e.getY()).getY(), findImage(e.getX(), e.getY()).getFilePath());
           removeImage(findImage(e.getX(), e.getY()));
                addImage(selected);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }`

Comment: change you're findImage method to the following: 

`public Image findImage(int x, int y){
        for (int i = images.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            if (i.containsXY(x, y)){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }`

Comment: so you are searching the array list from last to first because the last element in the list will be drawn at the top, so you'll find the top element first

Comment: ouh sry my mistake, you have to do `images.get(i).containsXY(x,y)`obviously

Comment: Since I was dealing with a Java Collection I had to do this in findeImage():         `Image[] imageArray = images.toArray(new Image[images.size()]);

            for (int i = imageArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
                if (imageArray[i].containsXY(x, y)){
                    return imageArray[i];
                }
            }
            return null;`

Comment: Thanks so much for your nudge in the right direction @Dimi!

Comment: no problem :) you're right, but since your initilized your `Collection` to an `ArrayList` you've could also done it like `((ArrayList) images).get(i)` but you're solution is fine too